# How can I make the useState append the data and not overrides it

Tags: reactjs

I am a bit new to react and hooks, There are many similar problems but I just need to understand it for my case.
I am getting the data from the backend as an array of objects I want to display each element, but the useSate function doesn't keep the old data of the loop so only the last element is displayed, Do I need to add another useEffect ? or the code is not correct ?

```
const [department, setdepartment] = useState([
    { departmentName: "Departm 1", departmentID: 1 },
    { departmentName: "Departm 2", departmentID: 1 },
    { departmentName: "Departm 3", departmentID: 1 },

useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8080/api/department")
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        for (let i = 0; i < response.data.data.length; i++) {
          let dep = {
            departmentName: response.data.data[i].name,
            departmentID: response.data.data[i]._id,
          };

          setdepartment([...department, dep]);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, []);
```

Comment: You may consider using the useReducer hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where `map` would be a better choice than a for loop. If you map over the result data, you can create the shape you want, and then set it all in state at once. By calling `setDepartment` on every iteration, you're causing the component to re-render with every iteration. If you transform with `.map` before calling `setDepartment`, you'll only re-render once.

```js
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8080/api/department")
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        const departmentData = response.data.data.map(({name, _id}) => {
          return {
            departmentName: name,
            departmentID: _id,
          };
        });
        setdepartment((prev) => [...prev, ...departmentData]);
      })
```

`prev` is the existing `department` data , it's a little simpler if you can overwrite the initial data:

```js
setdepartment(departmentData);
```

Comment: I see, thank you this works perfectly. But If you can explain to me a bit what's the problem with my solution?

Comment: Sure thing - I think your main issue has to do with how `setState` (or in your case `setdepartment`) works. React batches `setState` calls in a way that can overwrite state data in certain cases. This is one of those cases: you were overwriting the previous value of `department` with every iteration. By using the functional form of `setState`, you're reliably using up-to-date state. See the React docs on functional `setState` for more info: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates